# How can I reference the same switch case command multiple times in TCL?

Tags: switch-statement, tcl

Here I want to use the exact same switch as I used above. $list contains a,b & c. I want to print Apple Ball & Cat accordingly. I want to use/reference this switch statement multiple times

```
switch $blk {
       a {puts "Apple"}
       b {puts "Ball"}
       c {puts "Cat"}
       default {puts "Nothing"}
}

foreach item $list {
// Here I want to use the exact same switch as I used above. $list contains a,b & c. I want to print Apple Ball & Cat accordingly. I want to use/reference this switch statement multiple times
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to put the code you want to re-use in a proc, e.g.

```
proc myswitch item {
    switch $item {
        a {puts "Apple"}
        b {puts "Ball"}
        c {puts "Cat"}
        default {puts "Nothing"}
    }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
myswitch $blk

foreach item $list {
    myswitch $item
}
```

Comment: You can use `uplevel` with that to get access to the variables in the caller's scope.

Comment: @DonalFellows if you can give one example, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to share the script argument of the `switch` command:

```
set body {
       a {puts "Apple"}
       b {puts "Ball"}
       c {puts "Cat"}
       default {puts "Nothing"}
}

switch -- $blk $body
foreach item $list {
    switch -- $item $body
}
```

Comment: That approach does greatly reduce the efficiency of the issued code.